# Error: "reading schema error: error calling driver#connect" when configuring Table filters in the Hibernate Reverse Engineering File (reveng.xml)

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, oracle11g

I am having some problems trying to configure Hibernate in my Java Project. I was looking around the forum, but I could not find any solution. I am new to Hibernate, Could you please help me? Thanks in advance.

Here is my hibernate.cfg.xml file content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
                                     "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory name="ConexionHibernate">
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">hr</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:1521/xe</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">hr</property>
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

[This is how my DataBase Connection looks like in Oracle SQL Developer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9apA.png)

[This is the error itself when i try configure the tables.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKb6C.png)

Answer (score 1):

In your config jdbc driver is set for mysql and also the connection url is not correct, for oracle it's:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe</property>
```

Comment: Thank you! it was that! I also had to include the ojdbc6.jar file in my libraries folder. Now is working!